# Default DropDown height of ComboBox with IntegralHeight is TRUE

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

What will be the default maximum drop down height of `ComboBox` when `IntegralHeight` property is `true`?

When I am adding 30 items in `ComboBox`with default styles(

```
  IntegralHeight=True
```

and

```
   DropDownHeight=106
```

), scrollbar is not displayed in combobox. But when 35 items are added scrollbar is displayed.

So what is the default maximum drop down height of `ComboBox`?

Comment: you can check yourself, just start at 1, and add one item each time.

Answer (score 2):

The default DropDown Height is `106`.

When you set  `IntegralHeight=True` , the resizing of items happens when item size incresaes.

You can increase the height of dropdown by just increasing its font size as per your requirement.